# How can I concatenate output without auto-escaping image_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a column in my HTML table with negative and positive numbers. If the number is negative, I display a green arrow next to the number. If it's positive, I display a red arrow next to the number.

The neatest way I can think of doing this is to make a helper called `show_with_arrow` where I pass in the number. I'm trying to make the helper method pass back something like `-6 ⇓` or `10 ⇑`, the arrows being images.

In my `show` view:

```
<td><%= show_with_arrow keyword.compare_to(7.day.ago) %></td>
```

In my `helper` class:

```
def show_with_arrow(position_change)
    if position_change > 0
      "#{position_change} #{image_tag('bad_arrow.gif')}"
    elsif position_change < 0
      "#{position_change} #{image_tag('good_arrow.gif')}"
    else
      position_change
    end
end
```

And it's outputting:

```
-6 <img alt="Good_arrow" src="/images/good_arrow.gif?1295578152" />
```

instead of

```
-6 ⇓
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use raw() like so:

```
raw("#{position_change} #{image_tag('bad_arrow.gif')}")
```

You're on rails 3, right?

Comment: Oh boy, I was trying to put raw just before the image_tag. Didn't even think to pass the whole line into it. It works if I pass the whole string into it. Sigh :)

Comment: Hi Dobry, if @Satya's answer works for you consider accepting it.. :D